# JComboBox Dropdown Menu Not Obeying AlwaysOnTop

Tags: java, swing, awt, jcombobox, always-on-top

I have an always-on-top window that I want to remain above all other windows.  Using setAlwaysOnTop(true) seems to work for most purposes, but fails when it comes to JComboBox dropdown menus.  Is there any way to prevent this from happening?  Attached below is a SSCCE and picture of the undesired functionality.

EDIT: Not sure if the behavior is OS-dependent, but I'm noticing the issue on Windows 7 using Java 7.  On top is supported on this OS.

EDIT 2: Seems that JPopupMenu has an override on alwaysOnTop() to return true.  This is the source of the problem, since on-top components do not have a defined order in how they appear on top of each other (OS-dependent).  Worse still, the method is package private.  Quite problematic...

Undesired Behavior:

[image: Undesired Behavior]

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class OnTopTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        new OnTopTest();
    }

    public OnTopTest()
    {
        JDialog onTop = new OnTopWindow();
        JDialog other = new OtherWindow();

        System.out.println("IS ON TOP SUPPORTED? " + onTop.isAlwaysOnTopSupported());

        other.setVisible( true );
        onTop.setVisible( true );
    }


    private class OnTopWindow extends JDialog
    {
        public OnTopWindow()
        {
            setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

            JButton button = new JButton("Button");
            add( button, BorderLayout.CENTER );

            setSize( 100, 100 );

            setAlwaysOnTop( true );
        }
    }

    private class OtherWindow extends JDialog
    {
        public OtherWindow()
        {
            setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

            JTextField textField = new JTextField("Text");
            add( textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JButton button = new JButton("Button");
            add( button, BorderLayout.CENTER );

            JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox( new Object[] {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3"} );
            add( comboBox, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

            setSize( 200, 200 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the JComboBox were not at the bottom of its window, you could make it [lightweight](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setLightWeightPopupEnabled-boolean-).  Another possibility, if you don't have a large number of data items, is to use JRadioButtons instead of a JComboBox, since they are functionally identical (a one-of-many selection control).

Comment: Good call on the lightweight.  Moved the combo box to the top and it works fine (components are lightweight by default, if they don't go outside the bounds of the frame it would seem?).  Thanks VGR.

Comment: thats correct output, all Popup containers are heavyweight, then goes toFront, another limitation,unwanted  only one instance of popup can be visible on the creen, the same with lost focus, to extract popup (BasicComboPopup) to chanche islightweightcomponent (with pack)

Comment: @Ironcache have you ever got this to work ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Not really.  It can work by default if the combo box is within the bounds of the container (IE: component is lightweight).  If the combo box extends beyond the container, the component is inherently heavyweight, and the behavior is out of Java's hands.  Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is handled by the Operating System and that `Java` cannot force the `dropdown` to not overlap the other window, as searching for this without specifying `Java` reported the same behaviour in many different languages.

You can test with a `JMenu` to confirm, but I'm sure it will also happen as menus and some other controls (like dropdowns) will (by necessity) show above any other window.

Comment: This is true if the combo box is heavy weight, which it is inherently in this case, as it extends beyond the bounds of the JFrame.  If you have control over the position of the combo box, and can make it fit within the container, you can make it lightweight (which gives Java control over the OS, as it's not actually making a new OS-level window).